# QueryDict to string loses list within JSON

Tags: python, json, django

My request is of type QueryDict and I want to convert it to a JSON object or string so I can validate it against a JSON schema. One of the JSON fields contains a list, like so:

```
{
"message": "Hello!",
"people": ["Aaron", "Randy", "Chris", "Andrew"]
}
```

When I convert it to a string using json.dumps(), get the following:

```
'{"message": "Hello!", "people": "Andrew"}'
```

What is the best way to go about dealing with this situation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Convert your `QueryDict` into a standard Python `dict` and call `json.dumps()` on the resulting `dict`:

```
import json
from django.http import QueryDict

qd = QueryDict('people=Aaron&people=Randy&people=Chris&people=Andrew&message=Hello!')

>>> qd
<QueryDict: {u'message': [u'Hello!'], u'people': [u'Aaron', u'Randy', u'Chris', u'Andrew']}>
>>> json.dumps(qd)
'{"message": "Hello!", "people": "Andrew"}'
>>> json.dumps(dict(qd))
'{"message": ["Hello!"], "people": ["Aaron", "Randy", "Chris", "Andrew"]}'
```

If you don't like keys with a single value being represented as lists, you can do this:

```
>>> d = {k:v if len(v) > 1 else v[0] for k,v in qd.iterlists()}
>>> json.dumps(d)
'{"message": "Hello!", "people": ["Aaron", "Randy", "Chris", "Andrew"]}'
```

Comment: Shouldn't you call qd.dict()? It's a member function: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.dict

Comment: @jozzas, no, as documented in the link you reference, `QueryDict.dict()` includes only one element from the value list, not the full list as required by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

this way can handle loss case:

```
dq_dict = {k:v if len(v) > 1 else v[0] for k,v in qd.lists()}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**